# Defined function generates global name not defined

Tags: python, function

I'm really confused, I wrote this code and I'm trying to pull in some functions I defined, but I'm not passing the right information somewhere. Does anyone have any tips or pointers? I'm not sure how to describe what my problem is, but the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test3.py", line 54, in <module>
    bar()
  File "./test3.py", line 26, in disconnectvpn
    child.sendcontrol('c')
NameError: global name 'child' is not defined
```

My **fixed** program code looks like this:

```
def foo():
    child = pexpect.spawn ('./script.sh -arg1')
    child.expect ('(?i)user input:')
    child.sendline ('response')
    return child
def bar(child):
    child.sendcontrol('c')

a = foo()

bar(a)
```

Comment: you need to pass child variable to functions before using them

Comment: I don't see the definition of "child" anywhere... Is that your whole code?

Comment: Yeah that is the whole code, I'm looking up more info on passing child variables and how to define child other than how it is written def connectvpn():
    child = pexpect.spawn ('./vpn.sh -arg1')

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: Thanks Warwaruk, I was wondering where in the documentation on Python's website this was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first of all you need to return child object from `connectvpn()` and
   capture it
2. You need to pass it in `disconnectvpn()` before using it

Comment: I think I need to add the line `return child` to the end of my `def connectvpn()` function but I'm still trying to figure out how to pass the object to disconnectvpn()

Comment: try `def disconnectvpn(child)`

Comment: Ok I added `return child` to the end of my connectvpn() function, then I edited `def disconnectionvpn(child)` and I also edited my line where I called `disconnectvpn()` and made it `disconnectvpn(child)` as well. I still am getting child not defined which means I'm totally missing something **super basic**

Comment: Did you *save* the return value from `connectvpn`? Instead of simply calling it as in the code in the question, you need to assign it - so something like `child = connectvpn()`. Telling a function to return something does *not* automatically make that something available to the caller.

Comment: Thank you for responding everyone. I completely understand what is happening now, and how to fix it, but I still can't figure out the right way to implement the fix. This must be such a basic concept that it's probably making everyone shake their heads in wonder why I'm even asking, but I can't find a good example online that helps me get this. I'm new to "goto-less" programming, I programmed with GOTO statements in BASIC for years before discovering the "right" way of calling defined functions. This is my first attempt and it's confusing me, I'm not used to python. Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You just want pass the child variable from the function `connectvpn` to the function `disconnectvpn()`?

You just need to save the returned variable from `connectvpn()` and then use that variable as arguments in the `disconnectvpn` function.

For example:

```
a= connectvpn()

print "Establishing connection..." 

time.sleep(10) 

disconnectvpn(a)
```

Tell me if this was your question. 
Regards

Comment: Yes! That's all I needed to do, I updated my original question with the fixed code